# Combine 4 parameters into something that only three arguments?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've got some static data that I'm experimenting with in C# and the first method looks like this which is basically declaring them.

```
        public class PrivilegeProfiles
        {
        string PROFILE_ID;
        string COMPANY_CODE;
        string PRIVILEGE_CODE;

        public PrivilegeProfiles(string PROFILE_ID, string COMPANY_CODE, string PRIVILEGE_CODE)
        {
            this.PROFILE_ID = PROFILE_ID;
            this.COMPANY_CODE = COMPANY_CODE;
            this.PRIVILEGE_CODE = PRIVILEGE_CODE;
        }
    }
```

that's all fine and good but I've got a second method with a .Add keyword and since it only takes 3 arguments I can't add all the static data I need. PRIVILEGE_CODE has multiple bits of data where as PROFILE_ID and COMPANY_CODE only have one. Are there certain brackets I've gotta use or is there a way I've gotta format it for it to work?

```
 public ServiceResponse GetPrivileges() 
    {
        ServiceResponse sR = new ServiceResponse();

        List<PrivilegeProfiles> privilegeProfiles;

        privilegeProfiles.Add(new PrivilegeProfiles("Train Manager","GW",["DASuper" "DAAccess" "MRSuper", "MRAccess"]);


        sR.DataResponse=privilegeProfiles;
        return sR;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If parameter takes a string, you must pass a string. `["DASuper" "DAAccess" "MRSuper", "MRAccess"]` is not a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want the PRIVILEGE_CODE field to be an array of strings instead of a string. For example:

```
public class PrivilegeProfiles
    {
    string PROFILE_ID;
    string COMPANY_CODE;
    string[] PRIVILEGE_CODE;

    public PrivilegeProfiles(string aPROFILE_ID, string aCOMPANY_CODE, string[] aPRIVILEGE_CODE)
    {
        this.PROFILE_ID = aPROFILE_ID;
        this.COMPANY_CODE = aCOMPANY_CODE;
        this.PRIVILEGE_CODE = aPRIVILEGE_CODE;
    }
}
```

and

```
public ServiceResponse GetPrivileges() 
{
    ServiceResponse sR = new ServiceResponse();

    List<PrivilegeProfiles> privilegeProfiles;

    privilegeProfiles.Add(new PrivilegeProfiles("Train Manager","GW", new string[] {"DASuper","DAAccess","MRSuper","MRAccess"});


    sR.DataResponse=privilegeProfiles;
    return sR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either add more variables to your PrivilegeProfiles class that can hold all the information you have or you find a format so that all your PRIVILEGE_CODE data fits into a string. Some examples for your `["DASuper" "DAAccess" "MRSuper", "MRAccess"]` as a string could be:

- "DASuper,DAAccess,MRSuper,MRAccess"
- "DASuper;DAAccess;MRSuper;MRAccess"
- "DASuper DAAccess MRSuper MRAccess"

whatever you please